# How do I compress multiple files into one archive using lzma?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, compression

Looking at the options of `xz` and `lzma`, I can't for the life of me figure out how to compress multiple files into one archive. I know it is possible because I've uncompressed a `.lzma` file and it opened a ton of songs.
If i try doing `lzma -k file file file file` it just compresses each one individually. Is there an obvious option or argument I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing you could do is use tar:

```
tar cf files.lzma --lzma file1 file2 ... fileN
```

Or, simpler,

```
tar cf files.lzma --lzma file*
```

That creates the `files.lzma` archive which you can then unpack using:

```
tar xf files.lzma
```

Comment: It's worthwhile to point out that, unlike zip, rar, arj on windows et al the common tools on unix/linux systems operate on streams, hence commonly have no option to create a single archive file.

Comment: @tink what common tools are you referring to? `gzip` and `tar` can.

Comment: gzip, bzip2, compress ... I can't see any mention of compressing several files into one archive using gzip alone.  Concatenating the content of several files into one using -c with a redirect doesn't count :)

Comment: @tink While it's true that the standard Linux archiving tools (`gzip`, `bzip2`, `xz`, etc.) can only compress single files, you can combine those files into a `tar` archive first and then compress the archive. This is generally accepted practice on *nix systems, and can even be done directly within `tar` by using the `-z` (gzip), `-j` (bzip2), or `-J` (xz) switches to automatically compress the archive stream after creation (check your system's `tar` man page for the exact switches since they can differ between systems/implementations).

Answer (score 0):

man lzma

EXAMPLES

Basics

Compress the file foo into foo.xz using the default compression level (-6), and remove foo if compression is successful:

```
xz foo
```

Decompress bar.xz into bar and don't remove bar.xz even if decompression is successful:

```
xz -dk bar.xz
```

Create baz.tar.xz with the preset -4e (-4 --extreme), which is slower than e.g. the default -6, but needs less memory for compression and decompression (48 MiB and 5 MiB, respectively):

```
tar cf - baz | xz -4e > baz.tar.xz
```

A mix of compressed and uncompressed files can be decompressed to standard output with a single command:

```
xz -dcf a.txt b.txt.xz c.txt d.txt.lzma > abcd.txt
```